# How to do an action when a certain button is clicked

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

Basically, at the moment I am doing certain actions that are being held in an `ArrayList` and when I click the `Play` Button, they are being output to a `TextArea`. I have two other buttons, `Start` and `Stop`.

- When I click Start, every action that I do is supposed to start recording.
- When i click Stop, it stops recording the actions.
- When I click Play, the actions are supposed to be printed in the text area.

I have got the hard bit working but I just can't seem to implement the start and stop buttons. I will attach part of my code so you are able to see. Thanks in advance!!

```
public class jPanelBottom extends javax.swing.JPanel
{

private JTextField jtfBoundaryLength, jtfArea;
private JSlider jsShapes;
private JLabel jLabelBoundaryLength, jLabelArea, jLabelSlider;
private JButton jbStart, jbStop, jbPlay;
public static ActionPanel yes;

public jPanelBottom()
  {
    initComponents();


    jbStart = new JButton();
    jbStop.setText("Start");
    jbStart.setSize(80, 25);
    jbStart.setLocation(400, 95);
    this.add(jbStart);

    jbStop = new JButton();
    jbStop.setText("Stop");
    jbStop.setSize(80, 25);
    jbStop.setLocation(500, 95);
    this.add(jbStop);

    jbPlay = new JButton();
    jbPlay.setText("Play");
    jbPlay.setSize(80, 25);
    jbPlay.setLocation(600, 95);
    this.add(jbPlay);

    jbPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
      {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          {
            try{
            //jbStart.addActionListener(this);
            {   
                jbPlay.addActionListener(this);

            ArrayList<String> list = MyFrame.shape1.getArrayList();
            for (String s : list)
              {

                  ActionPanel.jtaWoof.append(s); 
                  ActionPanel.jtaWoof.append("\n");
              }              
           }}catch(Throwable ex){}}
      });
  }
```

I really appreciate any help!!

Comment: Why are you adding the ActionListener to the button very time actionPerformed is called?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. I am very new to programming

Comment: ... and why you **do  not** add `ActionListener` to your *Start* and *Stop* buttons, while you apparently expect them tp perform some action?

Comment: I am honestly not 100% sure how to do that correctly either

Comment: Then you need some education. You may want to try [Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html) Tutorial and see if you need to go back to more basic stuff.

Comment: _" I am doing certain actions that are being held in an ArrayList"_... What does that even mean? Do you have an ArrayList of ActionListeners?

Comment: _"When I click Play, the actions are supposed to be printed in the text area."_.. I think you need to clearly define what _"actions"_ is.

Comment: Sorry. The actions that I am referring to are when I click on my menu, three items appear, each time i click one of these items, it is stored in an arrayString. Whenever I click the Play button, the items that are stored within the arrayString are printed to the TextArea

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to add a general actionPerformed:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

[...]
    public Frame(){
        JButton Test = new JButton("Nutton Name");
        [...]
        Test.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Object src = e.getSource();
        if(src == Test){
            System.out.print("You've pressed Test!");
        }

    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the .addActionListener and to implement ActionListener to the class.
This is much easier than adding one every single time.